# How did I get the copy editor badge with 499 edits?

Tags: discussion, support, badges

On the SO Badges page it states that to receive the Copy Editor badge you must...

> Edit 500 posts (excluding own or deleted posts and tag edits)

On my profile page where it shows the number of edits, flags, and votes, I have `499 posts edited`, but I also have the Copy Editor badge. How is this possible?

Comment: i see [522 suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4084574/mhatch?tab=activity&sort=suggestions&page=1)..

Comment: @KevinB Does it count suggested edits? Rather than accepted ones?

Comment: Could you have an approved edit on a deleted post?

Comment: the data doesn't seem to support that, since you received it 2 days ago... not sure. Could just be caching?

Comment: @dckuehn That is, of course, possible... but I don't have the ability to know if that has happened.

Comment: "excluding own or deleted posts..." don't think it's a deleted post.

Comment: @dckuehn The badge description also clearly says that it excludes deleted posts.

Comment: I'm embarrased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you edited 500 posts, got the badge and then someone deleted one of those 500 posts.

Once awarded, non-tag badges are not recinded if you no longer meet the qualifying requirements.